# How do I submit a Rails AJAX form using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

How can I submit an AJAX form in rails by using a button?

My Code:

```
Controller:

def list
  @events = ExternalEvent.all
  if !params[:city_id].nil?
    @events = @events.where(city_id: params[:city_id])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end

list.js.erb:

$('#events').html("<%= j render 'events' %>");

list.erb:

<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<div id='events'>
  <%= render 'events' %>
</div>

_events.erb:

<%= form_tag('/list', remote: true) do %>
  <input name='city_id' value='2'>
  <input type='Submit'>
<% end %>
<table>
  <% for event in @events %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= event.name %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

On clicking submit the AJAX form is submitted successfully.

But how do I submit the form from outside the form.
Using

```
<input type='button' onclick="document.getElementById('get_event').onsubmit()" value="Change City">
```

returns a JavaScript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
  onclick
```

How do I submit this form externally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following way

```
<form id="get_event">
<input type='button' onclick="document.getElementById('get_event').submit();" value="Change City">
    </form>
```

issubmit() is not a function , but submit() is.

**For AJAX** use Ajax call to submit form without page reload :

```
<form id="get_event">
<input type='button' onclick="submitFrmAjax();" value="Change City">
</form>

<script>
    function submitFrmAjax(){
       $.ajax({
    //Your ajax code here to submit from via AJAX. refer jquery site . I gave sample eg.
             url : "Your URL or file name on server",
             data : $("form").serialize()
        });
    }
</script>
```

[Demo for Regular Submit](http://jsfiddle.net/vgbj5gmq/3/)

[Demo : Sample ajax submit , see network tab in firebug](http://jsfiddle.net/vgbj5gmq/13/)

Comment: Please refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for that . It contains URL , data to be sent , data type of returned data etc.

Comment: Works... thanks.. but i thought rails should have something to do this explicitly

Comment: @Zeutheus , No  Ruby is Server side language like PHP . And ajax , jquery are for Front end . So no matter what you use on Server side . AJAX , jquery is same for All like HTML .  :)

Comment: I know it doesn't matter but just FYI, onsubmit() still works when I use Rails 2.3... It does an AJAX submit..

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem arise here

```
<%= form_tag('/list', remote: true) do %>
```

change this with

```
<%= form_tag(:list, :url => '/list', remote: true) do %>
```

If list model are accessible.