# Using Ajax in Rails to do a search on keyup of the search box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've closely reviewed all the SO posts on this topic and I still cannot get this to work. Can anyone spot the problem? I will include my code below.

[search.html.erb]

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
  <h1>Search</h1>
    <%= form_tag(do_search_items_path, method: "post", remote: true, authenticity_token: true, role: "form",class: "form") do %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">And/Or:</label>
        <%= select_tag(:all_any,
            options_for_select(
              [['match all conditions', "all"],
               ["match any conditions", "any"]]), class: "form-control") %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category:</label>
        <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), class: "form-control") %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Search for:</label>
        <%= text_field_tag(:title, "", class: "form-control", onkeyup: "$(this).parent('div').parent('form').trigger('submit.rails')") %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Return matching or non-matching items</label>
        <%= select_tag(:match_no_match,
              options_for_select(
              [['only matching', "match"],
               ['only non matching', "nomatch"]
              ]), class: "form-control") %>
      </div>

      <%= submit_tag("Search", class: "btn btn-default" ) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

[do_search.js.erb]

```
$('#search_results').html("<%= escape_javascript (render(partial: 'search_results')) %>");
```

[from items_controller.rb]

```
  def do_search
    match_parm = params.fetch(:match_no_match)
    all_any_parm = params.fetch(:all_any)
    title_parm = params.fetch(:title)
    cat_id_parm = params.fetch(:category_id)
    @items = Item.do_item_search(
          searchtitle: title_parm,
          catid: cat_id_parm.to_i,
          all_any: all_any_parm,
          match_no: match_parm)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

[search_results.html.erb]

#### Search Results

```
<%if @items.nil? || @items.length == 0%>
    <p>No Matches Found</p>
<% else %>
    <p><%= @items.length %> matches found</p>
    <%= render "index" %>
<% end %>
```

When I type into the search box, the controller gets called as I expect, but I get the error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in ItemsController#do_search
```

at this line in the items controller.rb

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Implying to me that the requested type to the Controller is not .js and giving me the error message.

#### Here's the whole error page:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in ItemsController#do_search
ActionController::UnknownFormat

Extracted source (around line #62):
60              match_no: match_parm)
61
62    respond_to do |format|
63      format.js
64    end
65  end

Rails.root: /mydev/form_and_pusher_demo

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:62:in `do_search'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"knh/nZgRNwSUv2Nmq76L2ShcNjy8ragcVfipUUTBz/bpZ2RW8m2ohHPtn7DhQ1w1BP7cSxAxkRIDr4E/6eaLug==",
 "all_any"=>"all",
 "category_id"=>"0",
 "title"=>"a",
 "match_no_match"=>"match"}
```

[routes.rb]

```
  resources :items do
    collection do
      get 'search'
      post 'do_search'
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  end
```

Do you see what I am missing?

Comment: I would say to check if there is a `remote: true` in your form definition, but you got that covered. Just maybe do a double check, this kind of error is because of this mainly.

Comment: where is the javascript portion that responds to a key-up?

Comment: @trh: It's in the form field for the search: <%= text_field_tag(:title, "", class: "form-control", onkeyup: "$(this).parent('div').parent('form').trigger('submit.rails')") %>

Comment: @MurifoX : do a double check of where? I have the remote: true and by the way it works exactly right if I manually click the :submit button. That is, it invokes js and updates the search results with ajax.

Comment: @pitosalas can u post whole submitted error ?

Comment: Sorry - missed that.

Comment: @7urkm3n I added the whole error to the main question

Comment: and in your application.js  you are requiring UJS right?  i.e. - `//= require jquery_ujs`

Comment: Yes, in assets/javascripts/application.js there is that line. Is there any chance that it is not getting picked up? Could it have to do with turbolinks? Also, this app was generated with Rails 3 but was "ported" to Rails 4. So for example the boilerplate for application.js comes from Rails 3. Could that be a hint?

Comment: @pitosalas, can u try `format.js { render(partial: 'search_results')}`

Comment: it could be turbolinks, as it likes to cause prolbems (kind of doubt it in this case) -- but as long as you have jquery-rails in your Gemfile, then you should be fine

Comment: @pitosalas What version of rails r u running ?

Comment: @7urkm3n Rails 4.2.6... And that format.js line goes into the controller?

Comment: @pitosalas Yes, also did u try to use `respond_to do |format|` method  in other controllers ? Probably u r missing that method. Also hows yr `routes.rb` file looks like ?

Comment: @7urkm3n see main question... Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @pitosalas just check this answer https://railsforum.com/topic/1441-rails-4-respond-to-produces-actioncontrollerunknownformat/ he had kinda the same issue.

Comment: @7urkm3n thanks for link, but doesn't address my issue

Comment: @pitosalas, so farm just try for yrself to make sure, does it work on html pages, or just `render plain: @items` to make sure getting data all perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: [How do I submit a Rails AJAX form using onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577751/how-do-i-submit-a-rails-ajax-form-using-onclick)

Basically instead of having the "oclick" or "onkeyup" event use JS to try and simulate a "submit" I bypass that totally and use $.ajax to do a proper background request.

```
// Do the async post or get to the right URL and 
// use the .serialize to prepare the data for the server to use.

function submitFrmAjax(){
   $.ajax({
         url : "/items/do_search",
         data : $("form#search").serialize()
    });
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help on this!

Comment: I don't understand.  Did you remove the 'onkeyup'?  Where did you put this method and how did you reference it?